# Use robot_detection module for a large Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using python [robot_detection](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/robot-detection) to detect robots in a large logfile. I have imported the log file in to a dataframe and started to use the module. This works fine when the dataframe has very low number of lines. Otherwise it gets stuck. Is there any method to split the dataframe in to smaller portions? Or how could i use this module?

```
#Dataframe
df.columns = ['IP', 'Time', 'Method', 'Resource', 'Status', 'Bytes', 'Referrer', 'Agent']

for item in df['Agent']:

    a = robot_detection.is_robot(item)
    if a == True:
        count = count + 1
    else:
        ncount = ncount + 1
```

Comment: Where exactly does it get stuck? What do you mean by dataframe, one from Pandas library?

Comment: @Janne Karila : Yes Pandas dataframe, the problem is when the no of lines in the dataframe is large the program gets stuck and do not produce any results?

Comment: How many lines exactly do you have? I don't know if it might help to not use a for-loop.. you can try: `df.Agent.apply(robot_detection.is_robot).value_counts()`

Comment: @herrfz : there are around 50000 lines in one log file?But the is_robot works fine with around 100s of lines?

Comment: Well I don't know anything about robot_detection module, but a DataFrame with 50000 lines doesn't sound that much, really. And looking at your for-loop it seems like the function `is_robot` is not applied to the whole DataFrame but to each line, which I assume to contain one entry of the log. Thus I suggested to use `apply` instead.

Comment: @herrfz : yes that I have already implemented, Thanks! But how to reduce the size of the dataframe? Can I split it?

Comment: Add print statements to the code so you know if it is stuck in the `is_robot` function or in iterating the dataframe.

Comment: I don't know why you would still want to reduce the DataFrame, but anyway, how about just taking a subset of it, e.g. `df.iloc[:n_lines,:]` ?

Comment: @herrfz I have exactly 423244 lines in my dataframe! Sorry for the previous comment,I used  df.iloc[:n_lines,:] and after n_lines becomes > 100,000 the process get slower!

Comment: I see, I guess then you can split the DataFrame, apply `value_counts()` to each split, and then sum all the splits to get the final result.